# AlertDialog without context in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, dialog

I want to show an AlertDialog when a http get fails. The function showDialog (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html) has the parameter "@required BuildContext context", but I want to call the AlertDialog from my async function getNews(), which hasn't a context value.

By analogy with Java, where I use null for dialog without an owner, I tried to put context value to null, but it is not accepted.

This is my code:

```
  Future<dynamic> getNews() async {
    dynamic retVal;
    try {
      var response = await http.get(url));
      if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok) {
        retVal = jsonDecode(response.body);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      alertDlg(?????????, 'Error', e.toString());
  }
    return
    retVal;
  }

  static Future<void> alertDlg(context, String titolo, String messaggio) async {
    return showDialog<void>(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
              title: Text(titolo),
        ...
    );
  }
```

Comment: Pass your `Build` context from `StatefulWidget` where you'll display the http response to your `getNews()` function .

Comment: can you give an example please. I tried passing context to my new widget. It doesnt give any error but also doesnt show any alert

Comment: bypassing null not getting any compile time error but getting same Failed assertion: line   'context != null': is not true.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The dialog only needs the context to access it through an inherited navigateState.
You can make your own modified dialog, or use my lib to do this.

https://pub.dev/packages/get

With it you can open dialog from anywhere in your code without context by doing this:

```
Get.dialog(SimpleDialog());
```

Comment: That's not possible. You probably forgot to add "Get" to your MaterialApp. Change it to GetMaterialApp and everything will work.

Comment: like this  GetMaterialApp.dialog(SimpleDialog());

Comment: i tried this   GetMaterialApp(title: UtilString.submit); getting compile time error.

Comment: No, on your main file

Comment: Controller controller = Get.find(); by this to show dialog ?

Comment: i trying to show success dialog in api success response .

Comment: dont force a 3rd party lib if it is not needed. see the answer with `final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();`

Comment: Accepted answer is wrong? That's a huge overstatement to say the least. How come out of the numerous ways to achieve this, only `GetX`/`Get` (your) way is the only correct one? I respect the hard work done on `GetX` but you can't shove it down people throats. I'm surprised this was marked as the accepted answer.

Comment: The correct answer (now deleted) said "There is no way to do this in Flutter". I'm not pushing GetX anywhere, I just mentioned that it's possible to do this, just like GetX does.
The most voted answer came long after my answer, just compare the dates.

Comment: @jonatasBorges How will I close it without context ??

Comment: This answer states, "The accepted answer is wrong." However, this answer *is* the accepted answer. Is this like "this statement is false"? :)

Answer (score 125):

Solution without third-party libraries or storing `BuildContext`:

```dart
final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

void main() => runApp(
  MaterialApp(
    home: HomePage(),
    navigatorKey: navigatorKey, // Setting a global key for navigator
  ),
);

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Text('test')
        )
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: showMyDialog, // Calling the function without providing it BuildContext
      ),
    );
  }
}

void showMyDialog() {
  showDialog(
    context: navigatorKey.currentContext,
    builder: (context) => Center(
      child: Material(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: Text('Hello'),
      ),
    )
  );
}
```

After setting a global key for navigator (`navigatorKey` parameter of `MaterialApp` class), its current state becomes accessible from any part of the code. We can pass its context to the `showDialog` function. Make sure not to use it before the first frame is built, otherwise the state will be null.

Basically, dialogs are just another type of routes like `MaterialPageRoute` or `CupertinoPageRoute` - they are all derived from the `ModalRoute` class and their instances are pushed into `NavigatorState`. Context is only needed to get the current navigator's state. A new route can be pushed without having a context if we have a global navigator key:

```dart
navigatorKey.currentState.push(route)
```

Unfortunately, `_DialogRoute` class (...\flutter\lib\src\widgets\routes.dart) used in `showDialog` function is private and unaccessible, but you make your own dialog route class and push it into the navigator's stack.

**UPDATE**: `Navigator.of` method has been updated and it's no longer needed to pass subtree context.

Comment: Great hack! The `.overlay` saved my day! (I found that if directly use `navigatorKey.currentState.context`, it will not work because the showDialog needs a context *below* the Navigator context.)

Comment: How about using `navigatorKey.currentContext`? It seems to work, but I'm not sure if there are potential problems compared to `currentState.overlay.context`?

Comment: Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'overlay' was called on null.
E/flutter (30999): Receiver: null
E/flutter (30999): Tried calling: overlay

Comment: Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'overlay' was called on null. getting error

Comment: @MagnusW You're right, navigator state's context can now be passed, because `Navigator.of` method got updated.

Comment: @s.j Navigator's state is null. As I mentioned, do not access it before the first frame of the app is built (you're probably trying to do it in initState. You can use `addPostFrameCallback`).

Comment: @IgorKharakhordin  no, I trying to show a dialog in the API success method in but getting error of context, I follow the void showMyDialog()  method but still getting context error.

Comment: @s.j have you set `navigatorKey` parameter of `MaterialApp` class?

Comment: @IgorKharakhordin How if the navigatorKey has been used by `Catcher.navigatorKey`?

Comment: Nice solution saved me a lot of time

Comment: If you're sure your navigatorKey will already have a context by the time you want to show the dialog, force unwrap your currentContext variable like so `context: navigatorKey.currentContext!`

Comment: Is there something you can do to ensure that currentContext is not `null` early in the initialization of your app? I get nervous every time I put a `!` in my code. 

Comment: I get error "No Material widget found. ListTile widgets require a Material widget ancestor." when I try to create a dialog with that currentContext.

Comment: Perfect great solution, much appreciated! Took us actually even hours to notice that `showDialog()` is actually widget-specific due to its requirement of the `BuildContext`

Answer (score 2):

Catch the exception where you make the getNews call if you use await, else use the catchError property of the Future.

Answer (score 1):

So you need a `BuildContext` to create a dialog but you don't have access to it. That's a common problem, you can refer to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59179143/5502121) for one of the approaches to solve it (create a static dialog and show it from wherever you need).

Another approach you may consider is to pass the context when creating an async method or object as an argument. Make sure you null it when you're done.

Or you can make a flag (boolean) which becomes 'true' under a certain condition, and in one of the `build()` methods you always check that flag, and if it's 'true' - do your thing (show a dialog for instance).

Answer (score -3):

1. Install GetX with: flutter pub add get
2. create a dialog with Get.dialog
3. add these line

```
Get.dialog(
      Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
            child: Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(20),
                ),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Material(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      const Text("Dialog with GetX without context")
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          const SizedBox(width: 10),
                          Expanded(
                            child: ElevatedButton(
                              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                minimumSize: const Size(0, 45),
                                primary: Colors.green,
                                onPrimary: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                ),
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.pop(Get.overlayContext!, true);
                              },
                              child: const Text(
                                'Cerrar',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

done!

Answer (score -5):

Easiest way to show alert anywhere:
Use this package [link](https://pub.dev/packages/quickalert) and enter these lines wherever you want to show alert:

`QuickAlert.show( context: context, type: QuickAlertType.error, text: 'Error Message');`

Comment: But your solution with QuickAlert needs a BuildContext context. The question was about "AlertDialog without context".

Comment: I request you to please read the question carefully not just the heading. Secondly I didn't provide the context from the Build method of the class. I just provided the type of alert and the text.

Comment: void showAlert(type, text) {
    QuickAlert.show(
      context: context,
      type: type,
      text: text,
    );
  }