# How to get context in the any function of StatelessWidget?

Tags: flutter, statelesswidget, flutter-alertdialog

We want to show an AlertDialog after some asynchronous processing such as network processes.

When calling 'showAlertDialog ()' from an external class, I want to call it without context. Is there a good way?

```
class SplashPage extends StatelessWidget implements SplashView {
  BuildContext _context;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    this._context = context;
    ...
  }
```

I've considered the above method, but I'm worried about side issues.

Help

### My current code

```
class SplashPage extends StatelessWidget implements SplashView {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: MyStoreColors.eats_white1_ffffff,
      body: Center(
        child: new SvgPicture.asset('assets/ic_splash.svg'),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void showAlertDialog() {

    showDialog<void>(
      context: /*How to get context?*/,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Not in stock'),
          content: const Text('This item is no longer available'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Ok'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void moveToHomeContainer() {
  }

  @override
  void moveToLoginContainer() {
  }
}
```

Comment: and where will you use `showAlertDialog`? You could pass a `context` as parameter

Comment: Yea, why are you not using `showAlertDialog(BuildContext context)` ?

Comment: I try to use an architecture similar to MVP.
In this page, I want to check the app version when the view is bound to the presenter.
And I want to output the error message about the version check to `view.showAlertDialog()` in the presenter.

Comment: Are you talking about calling `presenter.checkAppVersion(context)` in `build()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should trigger rebuild when the async event complete, either convert your widget to `StatefulWidget` and call `setState()` or use a state management solution like Bloc.

For example using `StatefulWidget` your code will look like this:

```
class SplashPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<SplashPage> createState() => _SplashPageState();
}

class _SplashPageState extends State<SplashPage> implements SplashView {

  bool _asynOpDone = false;

  /// Call this when the async operation is done.
  void _onAsynOpDone() => setState(() => _asyncOpDone = true);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_asyncOpDone) showAlertDialog(context);

    return Scaffold(
      ...,
      ///
    );
  }

  @override
  void showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: ...,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This page is an intro screen with only one image view. Once built, views do not need to be rebuilt. By the way, should I use StatefulWidget to bring up an AlertDialog? I thought there was another good way to ask.

Answer (score 7):

To show an AlertDialog you need the context, but in StatelessWidget you do not have access to it directly as in StatefulWidget.

Few options are [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56280736/alertdialog-without-context-in-flutter):

- passing it as GlobalKey [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61773774/2726494)
- passing build context as parameter to any other function inside StatelessWidget
- use a service to inject the dialog without context [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60956122/2726494)

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply Builder pattern concept to simplify this.

There is a little example here.

[button_builder.dart](https://gist.github.com/itmarck/1af47719c8f0a5b2b487bc1f7d1d4f48#file-button_builder-dart)