# Does passing BuildContext inside a static method causes memory leak in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to display a dialog which will be reusable everywhere in my app. The dialog requires `BuildContext` so I created a class and added a static method to show the dialog and passed a `BuildContext` in the static method as parameters. Does this cause any memory leak?? As far as Native Android goes I know that passing activity context inside a static method causes method leak if the static method is returning an UI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Potentially yes. This will prevent the garbage collector from freeing memory from this object. As per answer in [this dart-lang issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/490) as long as there is a reachable reference - the object will be kept in memory.

So, in general, it is not recommended to store a `BuildContext` object in a static field.

But if you get a `BuildContext` of the top widget which is not going to be recreated within the lifetime spawn of the app - it should be ok. 
If it might be disposed - overwrite the `dispose()` method and clear the reference by assigning a `null` value.

As per the long-living async tasks - I don't recommend passing them a `BuildContext` because it will definitely cause a memory leak for as long the task will be executing.

Comment: so what is the solution what o pass at the place of context to show a dialog in model class