Regarding the issue of global monitoring of Bluetooth status navigation page
Flutter Version
Flutter 3.24.3 • channel stable
How to continuously monitor the status of Bluetooth at the global level using the Flutter framework? No matter which page you are on, when you hear that Bluetooth is turned off, you will directly jump to the page where Bluetooth is turned off. Can this be achieved?
If the current BuildContext instance is not obtained, there is no way to navigate. The navigatorKey property of MaterialApp cannot be used because the onGeneratedRoute property is not used. Is there any other way to achieve this requirement?
You can ignore the third-party plugin library. My problem now is that I cannot globally listen in Flutter and navigate to a new page based on the listening results, regardless of which page it is currently on. However, I cannot implement this (because the listener is not in the widget page) because I cannot obtain the context instance of the current page. This is because it is a global listening, not a specific page listening.
I have looked at the API of streamBuilder, and it reads streams and builds components. Can it only rely on widgets? Once the widget is relied upon, there will be a declaration cycle for the component. What I want is to globally monitor this state throughout the application and automatically redirect routes based on changes in state.
Regarding the navigation routing method, the articles I found are all about navigating in widgets where there is a context context. Because the above requirements are globally monitored and not limited to the context of the current active page, it is impossible to obtain the latest context value.

What should be the behaviour when the app is closed or in background ?

If the application is closed, it naturally means it has ended, or if the application is running in the background, it should continue to run and listen. This question seems unrelated to the current issue, right

Actually, this is related. Because In android there are 2 ways to listen broadcast receivers. one way you can always listen to changes event he app is closed, another way you can only listen when the app is running. So, for now I have working code for always listen changes and showing a Toast message. Let see if we can create your scenario.

Can the monitor automatically navigate to the specified page in the listener after hearing the status change? What I want is to globally monitor and push the navigation to a page where Bluetooth has been turned off after the Bluetooth connection is disconnected. On that page, you can request Bluetooth to be turned on, so there is no need to repeatedly add some judgments on each page.
Because the global listener does not have a context object in the widget.

you can navigate without context using a global key, the hard task is listening the bluetooth state.

Can you do it like this: just call a method and get the status of bluetooth if the bluetooth is turned off, then show the turned off screen, with a refresh button. If user manually turned on the bluetooth then on click on refresh button you can get the status of bluetooth and then navigate.

Do you want to use the GlobalKey object to assign a value to the navigatorKey property in MaterialApp? But there are several prerequisites for using navigatorKey. I did not use the onGeneratedRoute property and do not want to configure it because I do not want to affect the current normal state of the application.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/navigatorKey.html

This is the original text "The Navigator is only built if onGenerateRoute is not null; if it is null, navigatorKey must also be null."
We can ignore how to obtain Bluetooth status for now.

There are only two ways to navigate now. The first is to set the navigatorKey property of MaterialApp (which has a prerequisite for use), and the second is to navigate to places with context. Therefore, global listeners usually run silently in the background without context, and naturally cannot navigate to new pages.

When your navigation should done only when the app is running and in foreground then you can navigate without any problem.

Can you give a simple example? No need to provide code blocks, just provide the location and navigation method used.

What I tired to create is: when bluetooth is off then screen with red app bar will appear and when bluetooth is turned on then screen with green app bar will appear. also when the status is changed of bluetooth the screen will navigate accordingly. I have used (bluetooth_manager, go_router) packages Please have a look on this screen recording and let me know if any change is required or I should add the answer. https://imgur.com/a/gppGjvd

I looked at it, is this displaying the Bluetooth connection status on a single page? I didn't see any navigation for changes in the status of the page. Is this Bluetooth monitoring status global? (That is, there is only one entity, such as the implementation class of ChangeNotifier). Did you use the xxx.of (context) function to monitor the update of the state display and top color transformation?

As you can see the app bar color is changing, These are two screens and yes the monitoring is global.  I have used a function provided by "bluetooth_manager" which return stream and we can listen to it. and with the help of go_router's redirect method I am able to navigate to a particular screen based on bluetooth status. Also, I haven't use xxx.of(context) to monitor the update. There's no need. I have used go_router's method "router.refresh()".

I am adding the answer. We can discuss further if needed.

Packages used:

go_router
bluetooth_manager

Note: You need to ask for bluetooth permission manually. For this example, I enabled the bluetooth permission for this app manually from device settings.
Add permission in AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

main.dart
import 'package:bt_navigate/bluetooth_service.dart';
import 'package:bt_navigate/router.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

void main() {
  GoRouter router = AppRouter.setupRouter();
  final BluetoothService bluetoothService = BluetoothService();
  
  //Global monitoring
  bluetoothService.getBluetoothStateStream().listen((event) {
    print("event received: $event");
    router.refresh();
  });
  runApp(MyApp(router: router));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key, required this.router});

  final GoRouter router;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      routeInformationParser: router.routeInformationParser,
      routeInformationProvider: router.routeInformationProvider,
      routerDelegate: router.routerDelegate,
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: false),
    );
  }
}

router.dart
import 'package:bt_navigate/bluetooth_service.dart';
import 'package:bt_navigate/screens/bluetooth_off_screen.dart';
import 'package:bt_navigate/screens/home_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

class AppRouter {
  static GoRouter setupRouter() {
    const String homeRoute = "/";
    const String bluetoothOffRoute = "/bluetooth_off";

    final BluetoothService bluetoothService = BluetoothService();

    return GoRouter(
      initialLocation: homeRoute,
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: homeRoute,
          pageBuilder: (context, state) {
            return const MaterialPage(child: HomePage());
          },
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: bluetoothOffRoute,
          pageBuilder: (context, state) {
            return const MaterialPage(child: BluetoothOffScreen());
          },
        ),
      ],
      redirect: (context, state) async {
        // Check the Bluetooth status
        final isBluetoothOn = await bluetoothService.isBluetoothOn();

        // Define paths
        final bool onBluetoothPage = state.matchedLocation == bluetoothOffRoute;
        // final bool onHomePage = state.matchedLocation == "/";

        // Redirect logic
        if (!isBluetoothOn) {
          return bluetoothOffRoute; // Navigate to a Bluetooth-disabled page
        }
        if (onBluetoothPage && isBluetoothOn) {
          return homeRoute; // Navigate to the home page
        }
        return null; // No redirection
      },
    );
  }
}

bluetooth_service.dart
import 'package:bluetooth_manager/bluetooth_manager.dart';
import 'package:bluetooth_manager/models/bluetooth_models.dart';

class BluetoothService {
  // Private constructor
  BluetoothService._privateConstructor();

  // Singleton instance
  static final BluetoothService _instance = BluetoothService._privateConstructor();

  // Factory constructor to return the same instance
  factory BluetoothService() {
    return _instance;
  }

  // BluetoothManager instance
  final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = BluetoothManager();

  // Method to get the current Bluetooth state
  Future<bool> isBluetoothOn() async {
    final state = await bluetoothManager.getBluetoothState();
    return state == BluetoothState.on;
  }

  // Stream to listen to Bluetooth state changes
  Stream<BluetoothState> getBluetoothStateStream() {
    return bluetoothManager.getBluetoothStateStream();
  }
}

homepage.dart
import 'package:bt_navigate/bluetooth_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final BluetoothService bluetoothService = BluetoothService();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<bool> getBluetoothStatus() async {
    return await bluetoothService.isBluetoothOn();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.green,),
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
              child: FutureBuilder(
        future: getBluetoothStatus(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return Text("status: ${snapshot.data}");
        },
      ))),
    );
  }
}

bluetooth_off_screen.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BluetoothOffScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const BluetoothOffScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<BluetoothOffScreen> createState() => _BluetoothOffScreenState();
}

class _BluetoothOffScreenState extends State<BluetoothOffScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.red,),
      body: const Center(child: Text("Bluetooth status off")),
    );
  }
}

Output

Yes, I see that when the Bluetooth status changes, router. refresh() is called;, This triggers whether the redirect method needs to redirect to a specific page, which is a great method.

May I ask if you have a good implementation method for checking whether you have logged in or not when viewing details in the secondary list on the mobile app page, or by clicking on the specific menu at the bottom of the phone to check if you have logged in or not? If you have not logged in, a dialog box will pop up instead of a new page?

If you are logging user in using firebase. Then for logged in or not you need to check the currentUser!=null. Have a look on firebase login in flutter there are many tutorials. And for navigation you can use go_router's "redirect" method. You just need to create a dialog inside "redirect" method.

However, my understanding is that this will result in page reconstruction, and I want to avoid unnecessary reconstruction. What I mean is that you stay on a page and when the login expires, a login box will automatically pop up instead of refreshing the page before displaying the dialog box.

You can use a listener for that. Firebase provides a function something like "FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()". Inside this listener you can show dialog.

Or if you are not using firebase. Then you need to create your own stream to listen for login state changes.

I don't use Firebase, but one difficulty is that when you need to pop up a dialog box, your current page needs to include the widget code for the dialog box. However, if many pages need to pop up dialog boxes, they all need to include the code for this dialog box, which is not very convenient.

I feel like I can only use the dialog box APIs provided by Flutter such as showDialog.

You can use Globalkey to get the currentContext. No, need to use every page's context. Have a look: "https://stackoverflow.com/a/61773774/14071053". Also, you can use getx package to show dialog without using context.
